# How to grab a href value in a simplemodal call and pass the query string along?

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm trying to get a php page to load in a simplemodal window, and to pass a query string along, something like

```
<a href="my_script.php?var1=value1&var2=value2" class="simple_modal">
```

What JS code would I need to load the href value of the clicked link into a simplemodal window (via an iframe or any other mean) ?

Comment: @xaccrochheru , i took your href as example but you can use click of any element and get the href property through attr....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('a.simple_modal').click(
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get(this.href, function(data) {
            var resp = $('<div></div>').append(data); // wrap response
            $(resp).modal();
        });
    }
);
```

**UPDATE**: You may need to wrap the response in a div for proper handling in jQuery (see above)

Comment: Damn, I got home and tried various combinations based on you guys tips, none works :( my link opens, but no modal dialog shows up. I'm still struggling

Comment: Right now I'd relly like to know why this

$('.simple_modal').click(function() {
   $(this).attr("href").modal();
});

is not working..?

Comment: SimpleModal doesn't retrieve the URL for you; you have to get the data first, then create a modal with it.

Comment: Aaah... Hi Eric, thank you very much for your responses ; It's much more clear now. I think I'm going to chose a different route : Build my modal dialog into the page ; But I need to pass a value to it, and it's unclear to me how I should do that, can you tell me how to do this :

link one
link two
link three

and a hidden div, that when clicked would say "link (link #) has been clicked" see, this is just about the jquery call where the (link #) variable value is passed, that I can't figure out

Answer (score 0):

you can use the attr property to get the href value

```
    $("a").attr("href")

$('.simple_modal').click(function() {
   var hrefval= $(this).attr("href");

});
```

Comment: I think he needs to prevent default browser behavior as well, to not to move to the clicked page.